# The value of _stdout is incorrect

Tags: python, stdout

So brand new to programming, working with Python. This is literally my 3rd week of class. The assignment is as follows:

> You have to do your chemistry homework, but you hate looking up elements on the periodic table! Write a program that takes the name of an element (as a string, independent of case) from standard input and prints a double representing its atomic weight to standard output. Only implement the program for the first three elements, hydrogren, helium, and lithium, which have the respective atomic weights 1.008, 4.0026, and 6.94. If anything else is given as input, print the statement "Sorry, I don't recognize that element!" <

Okay, so an if/else check. nothing really different from the last 20-something assignments for this week.

So:

```
element = (input('Enter chemical name'))
name = element.lower()
if name == "hydrogen":
    print('Atomic weight: 1.008')
elif  name == "helium":
    print('Atomic weight: 4.0026')
elif  name == "lithium":
        print('Atomic weight: 6.94')
else:
    print('Sorry, I do not recognize that element!')
```

so the user inputs a name, that string gets passed to name through the lower function so it's all lower case. Then it's just an if/else cycle. Straight forward right?

Well MyProgrammingLab is throwing back the following error:

> The value of _stdout is incorrect.

So... yeah. What is _stdout? I've found that it's a built in function of Python. But I don't know what it actual does, or why it's being used in my program. I'm not calling it.

Comment: As it stands, your code does not compile - you need a statement after your `elif`.

Comment: I'm guessing MyProgrammingLab is some kind of answer-checking service. I suspect that the error message merely means either "this program is producing output that doesn't match what I expected" or "this program is crashing". I suggest running your program locally in an environment that gives you a more useful error message. For instance, on my machine I get `IndentationError: expected an indented block` on line 8, which is a much better diagnostic than "that's incorrect"

Comment: When asking questions about code that throws an error/exception, please post the complete Traceback.  Welcome to SO - please take the time to read [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: Sounds like MyProgrammingLab sucks at giving feedback or dealing with broken code. File a bug report and point to this question, because it should give you something more useful (i.e. check the return code and show you stderr). In the meantime, running the code on your own computer would be more informative.

Comment: @kevin
doh! I skipped a line when I was posting my code:

      "print('Atomic weight: 6.94')"

that statement should follow the elif name == "lithium":

As for the MyProgrammingLab it's some kind of online class system with a simulation check system. It's proving to be more frustrating them helpful, but the school is under contract and it's how I have to submit my assignments.

Comment: The question doesn't say to print `Atomic weight:`. Try removing that and see if it works

Comment: @user3080953 Well now I get a new error:
=  SyntaxError: invalid syntax (CTest.py, line 5)

Comment: Post your modified code and check your syntax (do your brackets and quotes match etc)

Comment: @user3080953 not much of a modification but here it is:

element = (input('Enter chemical name'))
name = element.lower()
if name == "hydrogen":
 print('1.008')
 elif  name == 'helium':
  print('4.0026')
 elif  name == "lithium":
  print('6.94')
else:
 print('Sorry, I do not recognize that element!')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`print` statement is missing for `elif`.

```
element = (raw_input('Enter chemical name'))
name = element.lower()
if name == "hydrogen":
    print('Atomic weight: 1.008')
elif  name == "helium":
    print('Atomic weight: 4.0026')
elif  name == "lithium":
    print('Atomic weight: 4.0026')
else:
    print('Sorry, I do not recognize that element!')
```

Comment: Probably worth mentioning why `raw_input` is used instead of `input`.

Comment: `raw_input` doesn't exist in Python 3 so will cause a `NameError`.

Comment: I agree that the missing statement in the original code was a problem, but from the post's comments it seems like that was a transcription error from composing the question and not in the code OP is actually running.

Comment: @dharmesh I skipped adding a line to my original post. I already have a print statement following the elif name == "lithium": updating original post.

Answer (score 2):

This is old but I am having this issue with `_stdout` not matching even though the code is correct. I figured out the solution.

myprogramminglab is comparing the `_stdout` value to the expected result without the prompts for the input.

For example it is expecting to only see 1.008 in `_stdout` for hydrogen but is seeing 'Enter chemical name 1.008' (Not to mention in the original example here there are other additional extra characters included and it is seeing 'Enter chemical name Atomic weight: 1.008' which is wrong).

So you have to trick it and use an empty input prompt.

Instead of `element = (input('Enter chemical name'))` use `element = (input())`